# HTML5 video tag fails to display high resolution videos

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, mobile, resolution

I have a simple webpage with a `<video>` tag. I tried assigning the `src` attribute of the video tag with URLs of two different videos, both about 2 and a half seconds long:

The first video has a frame resolution of **3840x2160**. JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u2sgawk7/2/

The second video has a frame resolution of **4096x2160**. JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u2sgawk7/3/

I'm encountering a problem with the second video when loading the webpage from Google Chrome on my mobile device (Galaxy S10). The first JSFiddle works perfectly fine on all devices. The second JSFiddle seems to work fine on desktop browsers, but simply displays a blank white screen when I open it on my mobile device (on Google Chrome for example).

I've tested this functionality using many other video files, and it is clear that the frame resolution is the decisive factor here: the problem occurred with every single video with a resolution of 4096x2160, and only with these videos.

I tried using this website: https://clideo.com/crop-video, to test whether or not it is even possible to display high resolution videos on mobile. I uploaded the second video (the one that was causing a white screen), and it was successfully displayed using a video tag on that website - both on desktop and on mobile!

What am I doing wrong? Any help to resolve this would be appreciated.

Once again just to clarify:

The issue **does not happen** on desktop browsers at all.

The issue **does not happen** on FireFox on my Galaxy S10.

The issue **happens** on every other browser I tried on my Galaxy S10, as well as in Safari on iPhone.

Comment: 404 for your sample videos now.
have you tried loading the mp4 directly into the browser on those devices to see if it's supported (so just put the url to the video into the address bar)
that resolution is asking the user to consume a lot of bandwidth, have you thought about hosting as HLS/Dash to optimize for device/layout?